# Webpack-hot-middleware with Koa 2.0

Tags: javascript, webpack, koa, webpack-hmr, koa2

Is there a way to integrate webpack-hot-middleware and webpack-dev-server with Koa? I am having hard time find working example which is not up to date fork of webpack-hot-middleware code.

Comment: It's always preferable to add a code with your question.

Comment: I don't really see the use case of using webpack-dev-server with Koa. Even if it should be possible indeed. +1 for Jaffer's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use [koa-webpack-hot-middleware](https://github.com/dayAlone/koa-webpack-hot-middleware) and wrap it with [koa-convert](https://github.com/koajs/convert)

Answer (score 1):

[koa-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-webpack) has been released and integrates both for Koa 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use koa2-connect to make connect/express middleware compatible with koa2.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa2-connect